# Sending Keys to the process started by my application not working

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I have created a windows form application using c# and I have an application that I want to start. I successfully start the application as administrator and the next thing I want to do is send the application some keys, Specifically Alt and arrow keys and enter. I use the FindWindow Function to find the window using its window name. I then set focus to my application using the SetForeground function, and then I finally send it the keys.

To check if my code is correct, I try to send the keys to notepad with the title "Untitled - Notepad" and it works. But if I replace that with the title of the application, it does not work. I have used the "spy++" tool which is provided by the Visual Studio. I start my application. Copy its class name and windows caption, paste it in the FindWindow function, But it still wouldnt work.

```cs
   [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
      public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

   [DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
      public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);



Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = finalString; 
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"; 
myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--AutoInject --EmulateController"; 
myProcess.Start(); String Pid = "" + myProcess.Id;

/* The variables found using spy++

Window Caption = [DEBUG] PS4 Macro - v0.5.2 (BETA)
Class Name = WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.31c915c_r6_ad1

*/

IntPtr AppHandle = FindWindow(null, "[DEBUG] PS4 Macro - v0.5.2 (BETA)"); 
if (AppHandle == IntPtr.Zero) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Something's wrong I can feel it");
    return;
} 
    SetForegroundWindow(AppHandle);
    SendKeys.SendWait("^(o)");
```

After Running this, The application runs but the key ctrl+o doesnt reach it.
It should recieve the ctrl+o command. Also Note: When the Application starts, The menu bar of my form does not turn white i.e. maybe it doesnt loses focus. Both the menu bars of my form and the application started are black colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use

```
AllowSetForegroundWindow(AppHandle);
SetForegroundWindow(AppHandle);
```

Enables the specified process to set the foreground window using the **SetForegroundWindow** function.